# a non-composite @EmbeddedId

Tags: jpa, hibernate-mapping

Is it possible/supported to have a `@javax.persistence.Id` or `@EmbeddedId` on a simple property (i.e. no composite class) nested in an inner (`@Embedded`) class?

The structure looks like this:

```json
{
    "something": {
        "id": 123456789, 
        ...
    }, 
    ...
},
```

There is no *many-to-anything* relationship involved in my case.
Also I have no control over the class/type/structure above.

I tried following:

```java
@Entity
class MyEntity {
    @Embedded
    Something something;

    @Embeddable
    class Something {
        // @Id
        @EmbeddedId
        Long id;

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

...and several other variations, but nothing seems to work. Usually I end up with an exception about my entity not having an identifier specified.
I would expect Hibernate to go through the `@Embedded` properties recursively and detecting the nested `@Id/EmbeddedId` eventually, but that does not seem to happen.

Do I need to replace the simple `Long id` with a composite id/class? Not sure it would even work but I would prefer avoiding that.

Also I would like to stick with `@Access(AccessType.FIELD)` which disqualifies the workaround of having `@Id` on some transient property directly in MyEntity, which would be pointing at MyEntity.Something.Id field.

I am looking for a clean solution that does not another level of complexity to the mapping please.
My sub-optimal solution meanwhile is not treating the entity.something.id as an `@Id` at all, having my own `@Id` added as entity.id instead, and dealing with the consequences later on in the process.

Comment: Is `Something` supposed to have other, non-id properties as well? If so, I'm afraid it's not supported by JPA

Comment: @crizzis Yes, it is supposed to have more properties. Ah OK, then. At least now I know there's no point trying. Thank you